# Data handling with nested repeat controls

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In my Application I, as a user, can create "items" through an XPage.
Those items have an undefined amount of entries in a list (a simple text list) which I create myself. Those entries will be used to generate `checkBoxes` later.

I have a list of customers. I can add multiple items to each customer. The items  are displayed inside a `repeat control`. Each row has an inner `repeat control` for the `checkBoxes` (generated from the `text list`).

Now my problem is, that I'm not sure how to handle the data or more precisely the checking/unchecking of the `checkBoxes` because I have an undefined number of items and an undefined number of the `checkBoxes` inside the items plus the `checkBoxes` are editable.

I hope my issue is clear. Please let me know if there is need for clarification or if you need some code - even though I think the problem lies purely with the logic in my head.

**EDIT:**
The custom control that is used in the customer XPage the checkBoxes I mentioned above are used for `status.

As you will see below I simply get the search keys for the items and use them to find the text lists to create the checkboxes.
Since the items are merely templates that are used for every user that logs in, I can't use those documents to save the state of the checkboxes.

The only thing I can think of at this moment is to actually create a document for every item that is being added to the customer and use this document as the storage - but isn't there a better way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/item.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="rowData" indexVar="rowIndex" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">
        <xp:this.value>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:return currentForm.getItemValue("itemSearchkey");}]]>
        </xp:this.value>

        <xp:div>

            <xp:button styleClass="accordion" id="button1">
                <xp:this.value>
                    <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                        var itemTitle = "";

                        if(!"".equals(rowData) || rowData != null) {
                            itemTitle = itemBean.getItemTitle(rowData);
                        }

                        return itemTitle;
                    }]]>
                </xp:this.value>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                    <xp:this.script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        // ... some code for the accordion to work
                    ]]>
                    </xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>

            <xp:div styleClass="panel">
                <xp:repeat id="repeat2" rows="30" var="rowDataStatus" indexVar="rowIndexStatus">
                    <xp:this.value>
                        <![CDATA[#{javascript:

                        var statusVector = null;

                        if(!"".equals(rowData) || rowData != null) {
                            statusVector = itemBean.getStatusList(rowData);
                        }

                        return statusVector;

                        }]]>
                    </xp:this.value>

                    <xp:checkBox id="checkBox1" checkedValue="true" uncheckedValue="false">
                        <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:return rowDataStatus;}]]></xp:this.text>
                    </xp:checkBox>

                </xp:repeat>
            </xp:div>

        </xp:div>

    </xp:repeat>
</xp:view>
```

To create the list that is used for the `checkBoxes` I use a simple `inputTextArea` in a separate custom control. `currentForm` is the datasource:

```
    ...
    <xp:inputTextarea id="statusList" value="#{currentForm.StatusList}"
        multipleSeparator="#{javascript:@NewLine()}" rows="8">
    </xp:inputTextarea>
    ...
```

Comment: Please show us some code and show us what you have tried so far :-)

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten I added the relevant part of the code and a brief description of what I am trying to do :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your situation, so I'm entering this as a comment instead of an answer. Also, I'm going to stay away from the word "item" as used in your description to avoid potential confusion with NotesItems, and call them "Things" instead. So in the customer doc you could have a NotesItem named "Things" that lists the names (or some other key) for each item. E.g., the Things item could have the value "111" : "234", "987".

Comment: So now you have a list of things for the customer.  Next, you take advantage of Domino's schemaless nature. You create one NotesItem per thing, using a naming convention, so the NotesItem "Thing111" contains a list of checkbox value, the NotesItem "Thing234" contains a list of checkbox items, and the Notesitem "Thing987" contains a list of checkbox items. You'll probably make these non-summary items in order to avoid internal limits, but since these are dynamically-generated NotesItems they're not going to appear in any views so that's no big deal - unless you need them to be searchable.

Comment: Note that things like this can get pretty hairy and in the pre xPages days it could lead to efficient but difficult to maintain soluations. But that's kind of the nature of things when you build complex multi-level stuff outside of the relational world, right? :-)  If it sounds like I've got your requirements right and it fits what you want to do, let me know and I'll re-enter the as an answer.